How to execute custom code when BGColor button is clicked in a table cell using AlloyEditor?
I'm using AlloyEditor, which is built on top of CKEditor, to create an editable content area in my application. I want to execute custom code when the BGColor button is clicked while the cursor is inside a table cell. Currently, I've added custom colors within the table configuration, and while the color changes are applied, they only affect the text background inside the <td> element. This happens because the BGColor button wraps the text in a <span> within the <td>, rather than applying the background color to the <td> itself.
How can I integrate a color picker specifically for table cells so that the background color is applied directly to the <td> element, instead of just the text inside it?
Below is my current code:
module.exports.buildEditor = function (element, readonly) {
    window.CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true

    var editor = AlloyEditor.editable(element, {
        readOnly: readonly,
        toolbars: {
            add: {
                tabIndex: 2,
                buttons: [ 'reference', 'table', 'image' ]
            },
            styles: {
                tabIndex: 1,
                selections: [
                    {
                        name: 'text',
                         buttons:[ 
                            "Copy",
                            "Paste",
                            "PasteFromWord",
                            "BGColor"
                        ],
                        test: AlloyEditor.SelectionTest.text
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'link',
                        buttons: [ 'linkEdit' ],
                        test: AlloyEditor.SelectionTest.link
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'image',
                        buttons: [ 'imageLeft', 'imageCenter', 'imageRight' ],
                        test: AlloyEditor.SelectionTest.image
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'table',
                        buttons: [ {
                            name: 'styles',
                            cfg: {
                                styles: [
                                    {
                                        name: 'Normal Table',
                                        style: {
                                            element: 'table',
                                            attributes: {
                                                'class': 'table'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'Striped Table',
                                        style: {
                                            element: 'table',
                                            attributes: {
                                                'class': 'table table-striped'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'Bordered Table',
                                        style: {
                                            element: 'table',
                                            attributes: {
                                                'class': 'table table-bordered'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'Condensed Table',
                                        style: {
                                            element: 'table',
                                            attributes: {
                                                'class': 'table table-condensed'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: 'BG Cell Strong Cyan',
                                        style: {
                                            element: 'td',
                                            styles: {
                                                'background-color': '#1ABC9C'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                 

                                ]
                            }
                        }, 'tableHeading', 'tableRow', 'tableColumn', 'tableCell', 'tableRemove' ],
                        getArrowBoxClasses: AlloyEditor.SelectionGetArrowBoxClasses.table,
                        setPosition: customSelectionSetPosition,
                        test: AlloyEditor.SelectionTest.table
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    })

    return editor;
}

I am expecting the best solution
